# Uso correcto de las variables $_SESSION[ ' ' ] en PHP ¿Que almacenar?

Tags: php, session

estoy mirando las `sessiones` en **PHP** realmente no es complicado pero que es lo que se suele **almacenar** en ellas, por ejemplo en el caso de que te **logees** me imagino que se guarda solo el nombre de **usuario** o **email** que es `unique` .

A parte de esos **datos** ¿que mas es recomendable guardar en las **sesiones**?

Comment: Entiendo que tienes muchas inquietudes y eso es bueno, pero las preguntas que hagas deben adaptarse al formato del sitio centrándote en algo concreto. Cuando preguntas por algo _recomendable_ puedes tener miles de opiniones como respuesta.

Comment: Disculpadme. Debo cerrar la pregunta entonces ? Un saludo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En las sesiones puedes guardar cualquier cosa. No obstante lo más útil suele ser:

- Guardar el identificador de usuario (bien sea su ID, nombre, email, etc.) ya que de esta manera no necesitas pedir al usuario que se identifique en cada petición.
- Guardar datos que necesites muy habitualmente. Aunque pudieses acceder a estos datos realizando una simple consulta a la DB, el tenerlos almacenados en la sesión te evitaría hacer esa(s) consulta(s) con el consecuente ahorro de recursos, peticiones, rendimiento,...